# Finding positive integer solutions to $a!+5^b=7^c$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

[This question:](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4276218/) "Solve: $a!+5^b=7^c$" was closed for lack of context, and probably lack of effort by OP. Nonetheless, the question is interesting in itself, and several particular solutions were given in the comments. I show here those given answers are nearly exhaustive, and pose a question about the one instance for which I have not yet obtained a which a full solution.

1. Based on parity alone, $a!$ must be even, hence $a \ge 2$
2. $\min (a!+5^b)=2!+5^0=3$, hence $c \ne 0$
3. If $a\ge 7$, then $7\mid a! \land 7\mid 7^c \Rightarrow 7\mid 5^b$. This is not possible, so $a<7$
4. Examine the case $b=0$. Here, $2\le a \le 6 \Rightarrow a! \in \{2,6,24,120,720\}$ and $a!+5^0=a!+1 \in \{3,7,25,121,721\}$. The only instance in which $a!+5^0=7^c$ is $3!+5^0=7$. **Solution 1** is $a=3,b=0,c=1$
5. If $b>0 \land a\ge 5$, then $5\mid a! \land 5\mid 5^b \Rightarrow 5\mid 7^c$. This is not possible, so $a<5$
6. $2\le a \le 4 \Rightarrow a! \in \{2,6,24\}$. We can examine each of these three cases individually.
7. $24+5^b=7^c$ is analyzed modulo $7$ and modulo $5$. First, $3+5^b\equiv 0 \bmod 7$ is true when $b$ has the form $6m+2$. Next, $4\equiv 7^c \equiv 2^c \bmod 5$ is true when $c$ has the form $4n+2$. In order to have integer solutions, this equation must be formulated $24+5^{6m+2}=7^{4n+2}$. Rearranging, $24=7^{2(2n+1)}-5^{2(3m+1)}$. This is simply the difference of two squares, viz: $24=(7^{(2n+1)}-5^{(3m+1)})(7^{(2n+1)}+5^{(3m+1)})$. This resolves $24$ into two factors, both of which are even and have no common factors other than $2$. The possiblities for this are $24=2\times 12$ and $24=4\times 6$. Moreover, for $m>1$ or $n>1$, the factor $(7^{(2n+1)}+5^{(3m+1)})$ is much larger than $24$ itself, so the only possible candidate is given by $m=n=0$, which sets $24=(7-5)(7+5)=2\cdot 12$ which is true, leading uniquely to **Solution 2:** $a=4,b=2,c=2$
8. $6+5^b=7^c$ is analyzed modulo $7$ and modulo $5$. First, $6+5^b\equiv 0 \bmod 7$ is true when $b$ has the form $6m$. Next, $1\equiv 7^c \equiv 2^c \bmod 5$ is true when $c$ has the form $4n$. As before, we derive $6=(7^{(2n)}-5^{(3m)})(7^{(2n)}+5^{(3m)})$. This plainly has no solutions because each of the factors is even and contains at least one factor of $2$, but $6$ has only one factor of $2$. So there are no solutions in this instance.
9. $2+5^b=7^c$ is analyzed modulo $7$ and modulo $5$. First, $2+5^b\equiv 0 \bmod 7$ is true when $b$ has the form $6m+1$. Next, $2\equiv 7^c \equiv 2^c \bmod 5$ is true when $c$ has the form $4n+1$. In order to have integer solutions, this equation must be formulated $2+5^{6m+1}=7^{4n+1}$. By inspection, when $m=n=0$, we get **Solution 3:** $a=2,b=1,c=1$. Here I am stopped. Since a solution exists, it is not likely that I can rule out larger solutions (i.e. for $mn \ge 1$) by modular arithmetic, and since the exponents in this case are odd, I cannot use the difference of two squares trick which afforded solutions in the previous cases.

**My question is:** Is there a method or strategy for evaluating the existence and nature of solutions to $2+5^{6m+1}=7^{4n+1}$ for $mn \ge 1$?

Comment: I believe (but am not certain) that $n=2$ is one of the known cases of the [generalized Catalan Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture). Perhaps the references in that link would settle the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $mn\geqslant 1$, then one has
$$5^{6m+1}\equiv 25\pmod{100}\qquad \text{and}\qquad 7^{4n+1}\equiv 7\pmod{100}$$
So, if $mn\geqslant 1$, then $2+5^{6m+1}=7^{4n+1}$ has no solutions.

Comment: Great answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, as to your paragraph 9,

> Since a solution exists, it is not likely that I can rule out larger
> solutions

is too pessimistic; a string of modular  statements may work.  Your $7^m = 5^n + 2$  becomes  $7^m -7 = 5^n -5$  or
$$ 7 (7^x - 1) = 5 ( 5^y - 1) $$
We **assume** $x,y \geq 1$  and hunt for a contradiction.

(I) since $7^x \equiv 1 \pmod 5,$  we calculate $4 | x.$  Well
$ 7^4 - 1 = 96 \cdot 25.$ As $4|x,$ we know $7^x - 1$  is divisible by said $2400;$

(II)  $7^x - 1$ is divisible by $25 = 5^2,$ but $5(5^y-1)$ is not divisible by $25$ Therefore $ 7 (7^x - 1) \neq 5 ( 5^y - 1) $

unless $x,y=0;$  there is no larger solution.

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

here are some links on this method, including the guy from whom I learned it

https://math.stackexchange.com/users/292972/gyumin-roh

[Exponential Diophantine equation $7^y + 2 = 3^x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1551324/exponential-diophantine-equation-7y-2-3x/1551383#1551383) Gyumin Roh answer from 2015

[Elementary solution of exponential Diophantine equation $2^x - 3^y = 7$.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1941354/elementary-solution-of-exponential-diophantine-equation-2x-3y-7)

[Elementary solution of exponential Diophantine equation $2^x - 3^y = 7$.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1941354/elementary-solution-of-exponential-diophantine-equation-2x-3y-7/1942409#1942409)  ME!  41, 31, 241, 17

[Finding solutions to the diophantine equation $7^a=3^b+100$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1946621/finding-solutions-to-the-diophantine-equation-7a-3b100/1946810#1946810)   343 - 243 =
100

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2100780/is-2m-1-ever-a-power-of-3-for-m-3/2100847#2100847

[The diophantine equation $5\times 2^{x-4}=3^y-1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2858769/the-diophantine-equation-5-times-2x-4-3y-1/2858976#2858976)

[Equation in integers $7^x-3^y=4$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3220085/equation-in-integers-7x-3y-4/3220132#3220132)

[Solve in $\mathbb N^{2}$ the following equation : $5^{2x}-3\cdot2^{2y}+5^{x}2^{y-1}-2^{y-1}-2\cdot5^{x}+1=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3383436/solve-in-mathbb-n2-the-following-equation-52x-3-cdot22y5x2y/3383501#3383501)

[Solve Diophantine equation: $2^x=5^y+3$ for non-negative integers $x,y$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3493828/solve-diophantine-equation-2x-5y3-for-non-negative-integers-x-y/3494267#3494267)  128 - 125 = 3

[Diophantine equation power of 7 and 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3818669/diophantine-equation-power-of-7-and-2/3818694#3818694)

[Find natural numbers a,b such that $|3^a-2^b|=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3873689/find-natural-numbers-a-b-such-that-3a-2b-1)  did +-1

[Finding all natural $x$, $y$, $z$ satisfying $7^x+1=3^y+5^z$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4006046/finding-all-natural-x-y-z-satisfying-7x1-3y5z)

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4155854/how-do-we-find-all-k-s-in-mathbbn-where-5s-2-3k/4156003#4156003 5-3=2

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

Comment: Very good references! I can see now that mathlove's answer was not just a bit of arcane knowledge on his part, but can be logically arrived at. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Once you establish $2\le a\le4$, you can treat the six possibilities with $b\lt2$ individually, so it remains to consider $a!+5^b=7^c$ with $b\ge2$, in which case we have $7^c$ mod $25$ is either $2$, $6$, or $-1$.  But the powers of $7$ mod $25$ are $1$, $7$, $-1$, and $-7$. So the only possibility with $b\ge2$ is $4!+5^b=7^c$. Moreover, closer inspection of the powers of $7$ mod $25$ shows $7^c\equiv-1$ mod $25$ implies $c$ is even (and positive), at which point an argument mod $8$ tells us $b$ must also be even. Since $7^{2m}-5^{2n}=(7^n-5^n)(7^n+5^n)\ge24$ if $m$ and $n$ are both positive, we find $4!+5^2=7^2$ is the only solution with $b\ge2$.

(For completeness, of the six possibilities with $b\lt2$, only two are powers of $7$, namely $3!+5^0$ and $2!+5^1$.)